# Adding margin to top of DialogViewController.TableView in MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: uitableview, uiview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a MonoTouch.Dialog `DialogViewController` which adds a custom `UIView` to the `NavigationItem.Views` object.

The `UIView` has a height of 25, and it's frame is set as follows:

```
Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0f, 44f, UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Width, 25f);
```

[image]

```
_toolbar = new UIView();
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Add (_toolbar);
```

How do I make the tableview appear after the `UIView`?

Comment: You need to add a header to the `UITableView`, which I'm not sure how to do with MonoTouch.Dialog (there is a method on `UITableViewSource` for it).  Hopefully someone can chime in.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work: `this.TableView.TableHeaderView = new UIView(new RectangleF(0, 0, _toolbar.Frame.Width, _toolbar.Frame.Height));`. Miguel suggested a different way below, which I can;t seem to get to work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I couldn't get Miguel's answer working, I ended up using jonathanpeppers idea from above and set the `UITableView.HeaderView` property to be a view which was the same size as the `UIView` I had added to the bottom of the `UINavigationBar`.

```
this.TableView.HeaderView = new UIView (new RectangleF(0, 0, 25f, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override the LoadView() method in a subclass of DialogViewController, and manually resize the UITableView in there to ensure that it does not take over the space that you are taking for the custom view.

Comment: Do I resize the `UITableView` using `this.TableView.Frame` ? As I set the frame, but it doesn't seem to update the UI with the new frame?